# Why this block is not trimming string

Tags: string, trim, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am trying following block to trim leading spaces from the sent string:

```
trimleading := [ :str|
    ch := (str byteAt: 1).          "get first character: ERROR HERE"
    ret := str copyFrom: 1.         "make a copy of sent string"
    [ch = ' '] whileTrue: [         "while first char is space"
        ret := (ret copyFrom: 2).   "copy from 2nd char"
        ch := ret byteAt: 1.        "again test first char"
        ].
    ret                             "value is modified string"
].

('>>',(trimleading value: '    this is a test  '),'<<') displayNl.
```

It works without any error but does not remove leading spaces from the sent string. The return value is identical to sent string.

Apparently, first character `ch` is not being picked up. `at:` is also not working instead of `byteAt:`.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the first element as a byte, which is a not a Character but a number, to a string with one Space character. In Smalltalk integers, characters and strings are different, so you should compare against the corresponding type. In this case you can get the first character of the string with `at:` instead of `byteAt:`, or compare to the ascii value of space, which is 32, or `Character space asciiValue` or `$  asciiValue`. Here is one possible solution:

```
    trimleading := [ :str | 
    ch := str at: 1.
    ret := str copyFrom: 1 to: str size.
    [ ch = Character space ]
        whileTrue: [ ret := ret copyFrom: 2 to: ret size.
            ch := ret at: 1 ].
    ret ].
    ^ ('>>' , (trimleading value: '    this is a test  ') , '<<')
        displayNl
```

as you may have noticed, I changed `copyFrom:` to `copyFrom:to:`. This is because, unlike what one would think, `copyFrom:` doesn't copy from the position passed to the end of the string, but tries to copy the receiver from another object (this behavior is inherited from `Object`).

There are quite a few other possible improvements and simplifications to your code, I leave that to you as an exercise.

Comment: Could you give some hints about other improvements possible?

Comment: Ok! 1) you are copying the string on each iteration, which is inefficient. You may better find the index of the first non-space character. 2) You may use isSeparator to also handle tabs and cr. 3) you can avoid manually looping by using of some functionality inherited by String, like #findFirst:, which in gst returns the index of the first element that matches or 0 if absent. In the end you may have something like this: `[:str | start := str findFirst: [:ch | ch isSeparator not]. start = 0 ifTrue: [''] ifFalse: [str copyFrom: start to: str size]]`.

Comment: Should it not be `ifTrue: [str]` rather than `ifTrue: ['']` (in your comment above)?

Comment: If start is zero there either were all separators or either was an empty string. In the first case you would still need to remove the spaces.

Comment: Ok. I get it. It should have been obvious.